# UINavigationBar back button always become blue after dismissing search bar

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I have a pretty standard iOS page layout like the following. There's a search bar and there's a back button on the navbar to go back to the parent VC.

I have code to set the tint color of the navbar into some custom color, like the following:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = COLOR
```

which works fine. However, if I click on the search bar (which brings it to the top and focuses on it) and then dismiss it, the back button becomes apple default blue. If I go to another app then come back, or use the interactive pop recognizer to go back to the parent VC but cancel it midway (so I return to this VC), the black color is restored. However, even if I call the above method in `didDismissSearchController(_ searchController: UISearchController)`, I can't set the color to something other than blue.

I think it's likely an Apple bug. That said, I'd love to know if there may be a hack to make it work. Fwiw, when inspecting the view hierarchy, the navbar actually has the correct tint color, but the back button doesn't. Setting tint color for the back button however has no effect whatsoever.

[image]

Comment: If you want to see what I'm talking about, go to Apple's Notes app, enter any folder (so there's a back button), click on the search bar and then click away, and see the back button changing from yellow to blue.

Comment: I'm seeing this bug as well.

Comment: Update: this seems to be fixed by Apple in iOS 13.2

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the similar issue in iOS 13.1

and the way I fixed it was a bit odd.
I added custom back button on navigation bar.
Here is my code

You can create a new back button in UISearchBarDelegate function `searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar)`

```
func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar)
{
    //Hide Cancel
    searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(false, animated: true)
    searchBar.text = String()
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
     if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
   createBackButton()
  }
}

func createBackButton() {

    let image = UIImage.init(named: "BackIcon")

    let customBackButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: image, style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(backButtonPressed))
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = customBackButton

    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment(.zero, for: .default)
}

@objc func backButtonPressed() {
        navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
```